# Change icon in Polymer core-icon

Tags: javascript, polymer

i'm using Polymer core-icon inside paper item in a paper dialog

```
<paper-dialog backdrop  id="sorting" heading="Sort by" transition="core-transition-bottom" >
               <core-menu selected="0" on-click="{{logTap}}" selectedItem="expand-more" id="mainMenu" >
                  <paper-item data-option="popularity">Popularity<core-icon   icon="expand-more"></core-icon> </paper-item>
                  <paper-item data-option="size">Size <core-icon   icon="expand-more"></core-icon>  </paper-item>
                  <paper-item data-option="price">Price <core-icon   icon="expand-more"></core-icon> </paper-item>
                </core-menu>
</paper-dialog>
```

Javascript

```
var menu = document.querySelector('core-menu');

   menu.addEventListener('click', function (e)
    {  
         var d = e.target.getAttribute('data-option');
         var dd = e.target.querySelector('core-icon');
         if(d){console.log(d);}
});
```

I'm having 2 problems here

1, when somebody click on the core-icon that target is that element

2 ,i need to toggle the icons betwwen "expand-more" and "expand-less" when somebody click on paper item

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm working with paper-icon-button and... I can change the icon property with javascript.  I presume any element that has an icon="" parameter can be updated thus as the property change will be flowing down to the encapsulated iron-icon element inside of it.

```
document.getElementById('yourID').onclick = function() {
    this.icon = 'more-horiz';
}
```